# How I can force Safari App to download a file in local machine?

Tags: safari, data-transfer, file

just wondering if in Safari 9.0.1 is possible force a file to download. With images is easy, right clock and "Save Image as..." but for files like svg, and other non visualizable files is hard to find a solution.

In the past a download window was always available, but now apparently not[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EAbF.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> (<kbd>Option</kbd>) down and click on the link to download the linked file (this is similar to the functionality found in Chrome). This will generally use the file name as supplied by the website.

You can also use the context menu ("right click" or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> click) and select the "Download  Linked File" or "Download Linked File As..." as required.

Answer (score 0):

I use the context menu (control click or right click) to download all manner of links. It really depends on how the web page you are browsing encodes the links and serves up the files though.

[image]